# useState set method and state not change in onClick function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

A state property is ReactNode, I want to change the property, and then get property value in some `onClick` functions.

But I find that state property value is not changed.

React code like this:

```
     import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
     import { Button } from 'antd';

     interface SomeData {
        id?: number;
        content?: React.ReactNode;
     }

     const Test = (): React.ReactElement => {
        const [someData, setSomeData] = useState<SomeData>({});

        const handleClick = (): void => {
            console.log('click event', someData);
        };

        const loadData = (): void => {
            const content = <Button onClick={handleClick}>button#1</Button>;
            setSomeData({ id: 10, content, });
        };

        useEffect(() => { loadData() }, []);


        return (
            <div>
                {someData.content}
                <Button onClick={handleClick}>button#2</Button>
            </div>
        );
     };
```

when I click `button#1`, the function `handleClick` console result is `click event {}`,

and click `button#2`, console result is `click event {id: 10, content: {…}}`.

why these two same click events give different results?

Comment: Try to put this line `const content = <Button onClick={handleClick}>button#1</Button>;` outside the `loadData` function.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what is happening:

1. When `Test` is first rendered, `someData` is an empty object, thus `{someData.content}` render nothing.
2. Your `useEffect` is called after the first render (because it has an empty dependencies array). In there, it save in `someData.content` a button, to which a `handleClick` function is linked.
   **NOTE:** This `handleClick` has its own closure, where `someData` is still an empty object, because the update on `someData` has not been done, yet.
3. When you click on `button#1`, you are calling the `handleClick` with its closure, in which `someData` is still an empty object.
4. Instead, when clicking on `button#2`, since `button#2` is rendered each time, its `handleClick` closure changes every time the render is done, thus the `someData` inside these `handleClick` are updated.

---

How you could fix this? It depends in what you actually want to do, because I can't understand.
You want that, when clicking on `button#1`, you set the `someData.id` to `1`, and then execute something? Let me know, and I'll try to help you more.

Comment: the code is a demonstration to show the  problem. and I know how to do it from your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "activate" your function "handleClick" when you click on your button, you should declare your function is in your function "class".

Example :

```js
import React, { Component, MouseEvent } from 'react';

export class Button extends Component {
  handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(event.currentTarget.tagName); // alerts BUTTON
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
  }
}
```

Source : https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/events/